# CSS Transition and Auto position

Tags: html, css

I have a div `.box` with which has absolute position set at the bottom of the parent div. It does not have the top position set because the height differs for different `.box` divs. On hover over the parent div, I want to change its `top` position to 0 with the transition effect.

In the following code transition does not work if I do not define the top position by default. I have tried using `top: auto` and it still does not work. How can I use transition without defining the top position.

Here's my code:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="box">
        Box
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.wrap{
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background: green;
}

.box{
    background: yellow;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    transition: all  0.9s ease 0s;
    top: 50%; /*== does not work without it ==*/
}

.wrap:hover .box{
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/5hs09apn/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A slight different approach than using top:  http://jsfiddle.net/5hs09apn/2/

set the `height` for the box, and on hover set it to `100%`; let the bottom be zero, so you don't even need to use `top`

```
.box{
    background: yellow;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
   height:20px;
    transition: all  1s ease 0s;
}

.wrap:hover .box{
   height:100%;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

```css
.wrap {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: green;
}
.box {
  background: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 20px;
  transition: all 1s ease 0s;
}
.wrap:hover .box {
  height: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="box">
    Box
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But the OP says the height differs for different `.box` divs

Comment: @VenkataKrishna.. yes, so it means he is setting that height for different  boxes.. right? so he just need to set height 100% on hover.. thats it

Comment: I believe what he meant was the height will be auto, ie based on the content. Eg: if the content of `.box` was lets say `Box<br/>Box<br/>`.
It would dynamically set the height. He would not be doing it manually.

Comment: @VenkataKrishna.. In that case you are right... But what i understood from question was, he is just setting height manually.. Maybe bad wording

Answer (score 1):

Add Top property in JQuery getting the current value of the Top of the `.box` using `position()`.
This will be dynamic allocation of Top and will not effect your condition of varying `.box` height.

While doing this, you will have to add the hover effect in the JQuery part too, since the Top will be defined here and CSS wont know what to do with the hover.

Check the Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/h82wcy5m/)

This is the JQuery function added:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var x = $('.box').position();
    var myTop = x.top;
    $('.box').css("top",myTop+"px");
    $('.box').css("transition","all  0.9s ease 0s");
    $('.wrap').bind('mouseover',function(){
        $('.box').css("top","0px");
        $('.box').css("bottom","0px");
    });
    $('.wrap').bind('mouseout',function(){
        $('.box').css("top",myTop+"px");
        $('.box').css("bottom","0px");
    });
});
```

Hope this gives you what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
.wrap:hover .box{
    margin-bottom: 100%;
}
```

And try with different percentages until you get one you like. It's crude but I think it can work.